# Handling configuration errors - global.asax?

Tags: .net, salesforce

I have a web application that uses a third party connector to get access to SalesForce. When I set it up everything works as it should. Contacts from SalesForce populates my application using membership providers.

However when i loose connection to SalesForce my site goes down throwing a "Configuration Error". I would like to be able to handle this error more gracefully if possible. Is there some way to do this, maybe in global.asax? Best case I would like to be able to disable the connection still having the website up and running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What component are you using to connect to SF?  Is there something you are configuring in web.config to set it up?  If there were a way to configure things programmatically, you might be able to wrap things in a try / catch.  Although you'd think that a good connector component would be able to handle SF being offline gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net, you can redirect your page to some custom error page.
For that you have to put following code into global.asax file.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect ("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what I would like to do is to handle the specific error for the connector and disable the connector until I have access to SalesForce again.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

- try-catch-finally
- Page_Error method
- Application_Error method
- Web.config file

If you just want to display error message on any parts of your page, use try-catch and you can continue with other transactions that do not require connection. Or you can use Page_Error to catch all unhanded errors on page-level or Application_Error (you will be using Global.asax file) for exceptions that are not handled by try-catch and Page_Error method. If you prefer to redirect to a different error page use  section on web.config.

For references, you can also read these articles:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134127/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081209-1.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355